# How to fix DTS package editor attempted to read or write protected memory?

Tags: sql, windows-vista, ssis

I'm trying to migrate some DTS packages from SQL Server 2000 to 2008 to see how much pain is involved. I've got the Standard version of SQL Server 2008 installed on my local machine.

I downloaded the  Microsoft SQL Server 2000 DTS Designer Components and Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Backward Compatibility Components  from [msdn](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905417) as recommended, copied the required dlls across also as recommended [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143755.aspx).

I converted one DTS package to a .dtsx file, and saw that the transform tasks had been turned into mini DTS packages embedded in the SSIS package.

THe problem is, when I try to edit them, I get the "Attempted to read or write protected memory..." error, at DTS.CDTSLegacyDesignerClass.ShowDesigner() according to the details if that helps.

Also the "Load DTS200 Package Internally" button is greyed out.

I'm using Windows Vista Professional - I suspect this might be the cause of my woes!

If anyone has experienced this and solved it, please help!!

Answer (score 1):

An update to this... the problem was definitely because of my Vista machine, though I dont know what exactly. Security permissions issue of some sort.

I followed the same steps on my XP machine and it has worked perfectly - I can open the packages and make changes inside them.